# Create trigger to insert new values into table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm sort of new to Pl/SQL and I'm trying to create a trigger that on every insert to the table inserts some more new values into the table.
For eg if I insert 12.01 into the table, the trigger should insert 12.01A, 12.01B, 12.01C into it.

It seems simple and I've created the following trigger but im getting quite a few errors.

```
create or replace trigger "BUILDRELEASEVERSIONS_T1" 
AFTER 
insert or update on "BUILDRELEASEVERSIONS" 
for each row 
begin 
DECLARE  
i number(1); 
v_version BuildReleaseVersions.version%TYPE; 
BEGIN  
v_version := :NEW.version; 
FOR i IN 1..5  
LOOP  
Insert into BuildReleaseVersions values  
(case  
when i=1 then concat(v_version,'B') 
when i=2 then concat(v_version,'C') 
end); 
end LOOP; 
end; 
end;
```

the errors im getting are:

```
Errors: TRIGGER BUILDRELEASEVERSIONS_T9
Line/Col: 8/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 12/7 PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Line/Col: 14/3 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
;
```

I'm unable to figure out where im going wrong. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You need a ; at the end of the insert statement ...end);

Comment: ... and a semicolon after `END LOOP` and a semicolon after the final `END`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you! that removed the last 2 errors however the first error still persists.. what could be causing it?

Comment: If you're running the same code all over again, it won't work. Use CREATE **OR REPLACE** TRIGGER .... Also, edit the question and post code you're working with now so that we wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: @Littlefoot I'll update the post.. the problem now is that the trigger is working but im getting an error that says 'Table is mutating, trigger/Function may not see it"

Comment: A trigger isn't really suitable for this. Apart from anything else, if you inserted '12.01' then the trigger would fire and insert '12.01B'; which would cause the trigger to fire and insert '12.01BB'; which would cause the trigger to fire... There are ways to avoid that, but still, that and the mutating table error are signs you shouldn't. Have you considered using a procedure to do all six inserts in one block, and then calling that instead of a manual insert?

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm realising now that it would go into an infinite loop if I used this trigger and so its preventing it. is it possible to do this same thing with a simple Select statement? but I want the values in the same column..

Comment: The mutating table error is because you're trying to modify the same table the trigger is against; it isn't getting as far as the infinite loop, but yes, that would eventually cause an error too. Not sure what you mean about a select; do you mean creating all four rows with a single insert statement?

Comment: @AlexPoole Im thinking of completely abandoning the trigger idea but I still need to be able to add '22.01B', '22.01C' or even if its not addded into the table just return those values with a simple select statement.. any idea how i could do that?

Comment: @AlexPoole For eg: I thought of select version, version||'B', version||'C' from tablename but that creates 3 different columns.. is it possible to get it all in one column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger would cause an infinite loop, as each insert would cause the trigger to fire, which would perform more inserts, which would cause the trigger to fire, which would perform more inserts, etc. If that happened Oracle would notice and terminate the loop with an error, though you might exceed the length of the version field first. But as you're trying to insert into the same table you'll get the mutating table error before it reaches that point anyway.

> is it possible to do this same thing with a simple Select statement?

You could do all of the inserts with a single insert statement, which uses a hierarchical query:

```
insert into buildreleaseversions (version)
select '12.01' || case level when 1 then null else chr(63 + level) end
from dual
connect by level <= 4
```

The query generates 4 rows, from the level limit; for each row it appends something to the base '12.01' value based on the level - for level it appends nothing, for the rest it generates a letter based on the offset into the ASCII range. 'A' is character 65, B is 66, C is 67; so those can be obtained by adding the level (2, 3, 4) to fixed value 63.

Your question refers to suffixes A to C, but your trigger only has B and C; if you don't want A then just adjust slightly:

```
insert into buildreleaseversions (version)
select '12.01' || case level when 1 then null else chr(64 + level) end
from dual
connect by level <= 3
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=715449737e43099ff59a038fa0f77bba)